# Node - Generate AES-CBC key and iv

Tags: node.js, encryption, aes

I am trying to get nodejs to run the equivalent of

`openssl enc -aes-192-cbc -k secret -P -md sha1`

As described here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVY3_9.7.0/com.ibm.einstall.doc/topics/t_einstall_GenerateAESkey.html

That is, generate a key/iv pair that will be compatible with other tools that expect AES CBC.

I could try to actually run `openssl` as a shell command, but I'm hoping there is a more node native way of doing so.

Could I generate 2 random hex of the correct length? One for iv and one for key?

Answer (score 4):

I am adding my own answer, using new NodeJS APIs available in v10:

```
let passphrase = "some passphrase"
let iv = crypto.randomBytes(16); // Initialization vector.
let salt = crypto.randomBytes(16);
let key = crypto.scryptSync(passphrase, salt, 16);
```

This generates a key and iv pair, compatible with `AES-128-CBC`

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to get nodejs to run the equivalent of
>
> `openssl enc -aes-192-cbc -k secret -P -md sha1`

If you literally want to reproduce the key/iv-generation aspect of this command in node, you can use some OpenSSL key derivation code [found in `crypto-js/cipher-core.js`](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/3.1.9/cipher-core.js#L773) as an example. It would leverage `EvpKDF` as follows, for example.

```
var Crypto = require("crypto-js");

var password = 'secret'
var salt = Crypto.lib.WordArray.random(64 / 8);
var keySize = 192 / 32;
var ivSize = 128 / 32;
var key = Crypto.algo.EvpKDF.create({ keySize: keySize + ivSize, hasher: Crypto.algo.SHA1 }).compute(password, salt);
var iv = Crypto.lib.WordArray.create(key.words.slice(keySize), ivSize * 4);
key.sigBytes = keySize * 4;

console.log("salt="+salt.toString().toUpperCase());
console.log("key="+key.toString().toUpperCase());
console.log("iv="+iv.toString().toUpperCase());
```

This mimics OpenSSL's key derivation function. Note that it applies a random salt to protect against dictionary attacks.

Running both commands to prove that they are equivalent, first the node script above:

```
$ node ./osslkdf.js 
salt=AFB2196A330BB67A
key=72DE44ADC3F86856BCBB5E5F01BC3D06178F0B61261550DE
iv=38D9942317D965C36C82CC7CFA1F48E7
```

and then OpenSSL:

```
$ openssl enc -aes-192-cbc -k secret -P -md sha1 -S AFB2196A330BB67A
*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
salt=AFB2196A330BB67A
key=72DE44ADC3F86856BCBB5E5F01BC3D06178F0B61261550DE
iv =38D9942317D965C36C82CC7CFA1F48E7
```

Note that the salt has to be explicitly given to reproduce the exact same results. Normally, the salt value would be stored with the ciphertext. The passphrase (`'secret'`) will have to be kept secret of course.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is some **random** data of the correct size for the key, and some **unique data** for the IV (only needs to be unique when used with that particular key).

If you use random data for the IV, you can assume the uniqueness requirement to be fulfilled.

You would need a secure random generator specifically for encryption - take a look at :  [`crypto.randomBytes(...)`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback)